# Groovy - How to print all variables in scope of script engine?

Tags: groovy, scope, workflow, flowable, groovyscriptengine

I am building workflows using a proprietary engine leveraging Flowable.
The engine comes with preloaded beans that can be used from groovy script tasks and I would like to introspect all variables in scope.

I used the following code:

```
this.binding.variables.each {k,v -> loggerApi.info("$k = $v")}
```

But it does not return all variables. There are additional variables like `statusApi` that are not returned from the binding.

Is there any other command I could execute to query all variables in scope of the script task?

Comment: you are doing right. `statusApi` - depends on how it's declared. all `def xyz` variables getting to be local and can't be listed.

Comment: Aaahh.. thanks a lot. I think they are instantiated using "@api" annotations in the spring boot framework. I'm not very familiar with the framework and I'm struggling to find information about their visibility scope, especially in the context of groovy script task in the flowable execution engine. 